# Struggling Hard With Godo

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I'm in the final boss of the pavilion in Wutai and I cannot stop him. My biggest problem being that he keeps making me small, when I attack him I do 1 damage. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

The item [Cornucopia](http://www.cavesofnarshe.com/ff7/w_item.php?item=Cornucopia) cures small. It's cheap at 150 gil and can easily be bought in bulk so you never run out.  Wearing the [Ribbon](http://www.cavesofnarshe.com/ff7/accessories.php?LowLim=20;UpLim=20) accessory also fixes this easily.

Comment: Excellent! I ended up running to Cosmo Canyon and picking some up. I downed the boss!

Comment: @Whitechapel you should mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise you to wear a Ribbon throughout the pagoda, and really the entire game, to prevent status ailments like this.  They're pretty common in this game and some of them are pretty rough.

Comment: I don't have access to a Ribbon, I'm still on disc 1!

Comment: You're almost certainly too low level to beat him as soon as you reach Wutai the first time (unless you've been grinding) anyway.  Also, there is a Ribbon on that disc - it's in the clock puzzle in the Temple of the Ancients, you can get it and go back to Wutai.  I do strongly recommend it for this fight unless you outlevel it by a lot - the time it'll take you to constantly manually cure it will hurt.

Comment: I did do a lot of grinding after the first couple attempts. I made it through all of it though! I was only hit with small once. It was by no means an easy boss fight, but I did it in roughly 15 minutes.